# Update column if another column contains a string

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table that contains three columns.

```
column1        column2     column3 
mytestdata     test 
myotherdata    test
```

I want to insert 'somestring' into column3 if column1 contains the value in column2

The result would look like:

```
column1        column2     column3 
mytestdata     test        'somestring' 
myotherdata    test
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the examples below using string concatenation will fail if column2 begins or ends with '%'

Comment: How can you guys, who are editing the tags, be sure of OPs RDBMS?

Comment: @Adrian The RDBMS was specified by the OP in a comment to an answer that has since been deleted.

Comment: @egrunin I updated my answer to overcome the potential `%` issue

Comment: The accepted answer is not correct, see my comment there.

Comment: The accepted answer correct for my case, where I dont have any '5%' type characters in my strings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQL Server:

```
UPDATE myTable
   SET column3 = 'somestring'
 WHERE column1 LIKE '%' + column2 + '%'
```

Comment: This is *not correct*. If column1 = '3456' and column2 = '5%', it will match (and it shouldn't).

Comment: Its correct for my case, where I dont have any '5%' type characters in my strings.

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server:

```
UPDATE theTable SET column3 = 'somestring' 
WHERE CHARINDEX (column2, column1) > 0
```

Answer (score 2):

You have several options, depending on the RDBMS.

For both MySQL and Oracle:

```
UPDATE yourTable
set column3 = 'somestring'
where INSTR(column2, column1) > 0
```

For SQL Server:

```
UPDATE yourTable
set column3 = 'somestring'
where CHARINDEX(column1, column2) > 0
```

Comment: What will happen if column2 = '5%'?

Comment: It will work also: where column1 like '%5%%' which is the same as '%5%'. I am quite sure about sql server, i believe other rdbms work same way.

Comment: Updated the answer to overcome the `%` potential issue

Comment: For some reason SSMS didnt like having a column name as the 2nd argument of the CONTAINS.  I used the wildcards and it worked.

Comment: `Cannot use a CONTAINS or FREETEXT predicate on table or indexed view 'yourTable' because it is not full-text indexed.`

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like below

```
UPDATE tmp
SET
   column3 = (CASE WHEN tmp.column1 like '%' + tmp.column2 + '%' THEN 'something' ELSE tmp.column3')
FROM
    tablename tmp
```